# ScrollView in ViewPager Fragment not working?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-scrollview

I have a ScrollView over the contents of a ViewPager fragment but it isn't scrolling. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. The bottom TableLayout does have dynamically added rows if this has anything to do with it? I have added the layout file below if anyone can shed any light on this. I have tried NestedScrollView but this doesn't work either. With the dynamically added TableLayout rows the RelativeLayout well exceeds the height of the screen. Anywhere with width/height of 0dp is sized in my Java file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:isScrollContainer="false"
android:scrollbars="none"
>



<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

<View
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:background="@color/colorRed"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    />

<TextView

    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
    />

<TableLayout

    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
   >

    <TableRow

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

<TextView

    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />

<TableLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

</TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Is your `ViewPager` working?

Comment: @H.Brooks - Yes the ViewPager is comprised of 3 pages and scrolls horizontally to each of them perfectly.

Comment: Ok and how are you implementing the above `scrollView` in your `ViewPager`?

Comment: Just with this XML file. It's not referenced at all in its corresponding Java file.

Comment: But the above is just a scrollView with no viewpager

Comment: Sorry, the above is the XML for a fragment within my ViewPager.